# How to decide which physical interface RMI Transport Layer should use?

Tags: java, rmi

When I use a remote reference from the client everything is OK. If I try to use this remote reference from the simu, the communication failed because the server try to use the IP from eth0. What bothers me is that the exception gets reported on the simulator.
I think I missed something?

**[EDIT]**
The simu provides this exception:

> java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to `eth0_IP`;
>
> nested exception is: java.net.SocketException: network is unreachable

[image: Network Configuration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [the `java.rmi.server.hostname` property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/rmi/javarmiproperties.html) to tell the RMI Registry which hostname or IP Adress to return in its RMI URLs.

This defaults to the IP address of the first interface on the system which explains why it's only working through `eth0`.

So you'll need something like:

```
String ipAddress = "10.1.2.3"; //IP address of eth1
System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname",ipAddress);
```

or

```
String hostname = "myserver"; //hostname that resolves for client and simu
System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname",hostname);
```

Comment: This property has to be set on the server, but I think the problem will occur for the client...

Comment: @chepseskaf - The setting on the server affects the data sent to the client.  The client is connecting to the RMI Registry via `eth1` and asking where the RMI service is and being told something like `rmi://eth0/yourservice`.  You can use the `java.rmi.server.hostname` property to set the hostname/IP address returned by the RMI Registry.

Comment: Thank you, it works! Sorry to be so slow, I was not seeing things the same way.

Comment: The setting does not 'tell the RMI Registry which hostname or IP Adress to return in its RMI URLs'. It affects the contents of the remote stub itself, when it is first constructed when the remote object it refers to is exported.